Looker Studio community visualization for basic shapes
I want to have custom CSS added to the basic shapes (rectangle and circle) in Looker Studio.
It seems like creating a community visualization is the only way to get there.
I try to dig through the whole setup and creation process. Created a cloud storage bucket and now want to start with the code.
However most of the tutorials, if helpful at all, show how to handle the data and settings.
I don't find a simple approach to create a community visualization for the rectangle item that let's me add the item and add a custom css field in the item settings.
Would gladly take any approach or idea how to get there.
